# Using ISampleGrabberCB::SampleCB

Tags: c#, bitmap, directshow, directshow.net

Hi i'm trying to use the `ISampleGrabberCB::SampleCB` to get the images from a live preview just before they are shown within my form.

I would like to be able to convert every new frame into a bitmap to be processed (e.g. scan + add watermark type image).

Currently I am trying to do it in the following way:

```
int ISampleGrabberCB.SampleCB(double SampleTime, IMediaSample sample)
    {
        int hr;
        IntPtr buffer;
        AMMediaType mediaType;
        VideoInfoHeader videoInfo;
        int frameWidth;
        int frameHeight;
        int stride;
        int bufferLength;


        hr = sample.GetPointer(out buffer);
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

        hr = sample.GetMediaType(out mediaType);
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

        bufferLength = sample.GetSize();

        try
        {
            videoInfo = new VideoInfoHeader();
            Marshal.PtrToStructure(mediaType.formatPtr, videoInfo);

            frameWidth = videoInfo.BmiHeader.Width;
            frameHeight = videoInfo.BmiHeader.Height;
            stride = frameWidth * (videoInfo.BmiHeader.BitCount / 8);

            CopyMemory(imageBuffer, buffer, bufferLength);                

            Bitmap bitmapOfFrame = new Bitmap(frameWidth, frameHeight, stride, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, buffer);
            bitmapOfFrame.Save("C:\\Users\\...\\...\\...\\....jpg");


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

This theoretically should get the media type which is then used to get the width, height and stride of the image which is then used to create the bitmap. The buffer is then obtained from the pointer of the IMediaSample.

However this does not seem to work (I am presuming this as the bitmap never saves). So how would I go about converting every new frame into a bitmap?

Additonal function where pins are set:

```
public void setupGraphForSampleGrabber(DsDevice webcamDevice, Control displayBox)
    {
        int hr;
        ISampleGrabber sampleGrabber = null;
        IPin capturePin = null;
        IPin samplePin = null;
        IPin renderPin = null;
        IBaseFilter captureFilter;
        filtergraph = new FilterGraph() as IFilterGraph2;

        try
        {


            //Add the webcam
            hr = filtergraph.AddSourceFilterForMoniker(webcamDevice.Mon, null, webcamDevice.Name, out captureFilter);
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

            //Get the still pin
            stillPin = DsFindPin.ByCategory(captureFilter, PinCategory.Still, 0);

            if (stillPin == null)
            {
                stillPin = DsFindPin.ByCategory(captureFilter, PinCategory.Preview, 0);
            }

            if (stillPin == null)
            {
                IPin outputPin = null;
                IPin inputPin = null;

                //As there is still no still pin set this to null
                videoControl = null;

                // Add a splitter
                IBaseFilter smartTee = (IBaseFilter)new SmartTee();

                try
                {
                    hr = filtergraph.AddFilter(smartTee, "SmartTee");
                    DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

                    //Obtain the capture pin from the webcam and the input pin from the spliter and assign them to the outputPin and inputPin respectivly
                    outputPin = DsFindPin.ByCategory(captureFilter, PinCategory.Capture, 0);
                    inputPin = DsFindPin.ByDirection(smartTee, PinDirection.Input, 0);

                    //Then connect both of them to the graph
                    hr = filtergraph.Connect(outputPin, inputPin);
                    DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

                    //Set the capture and still pins so we can use them with the rest of the program
                    stillPin = DsFindPin.ByName(smartTee, "Preview");
                    capturePin = DsFindPin.ByName(smartTee, "Capture");

                    setParameters(outputPin);

                }
                    //Release all the com objects to avoid problems as the program is to be used for extended periods

                finally
                {
                    if (outputPin != null)
                    {
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(outputPin);
                    }
                    if (outputPin != inputPin)
                    {
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(inputPin);
                    }
                    if (outputPin != smartTee)
                    {
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(smartTee);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                videoControl = captureFilter as IAMVideoControl;
                capturePin = DsFindPin.ByCategory(captureFilter, PinCategory.Capture, 0);
                setParameters(stillPin);
            }

            //Get interface
            sampleGrabber = new SampleGrabber() as ISampleGrabber;

            //Configure the samplegrabber
            IBaseFilter baseFilter = sampleGrabber as IBaseFilter;
            configureSampleGrabber(sampleGrabber);
            samplePin = DsFindPin.ByDirection(baseFilter, PinDirection.Input, 0);

            //Video Renderer
            IBaseFilter render = new VideoRendererDefault() as IBaseFilter;
            hr = filtergraph.AddFilter(render, "Renderer");
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

            renderPin = DsFindPin.ByDirection(render, PinDirection.Input, 0);

            //Add samplegrabber to graph
            hr = filtergraph.AddFilter(baseFilter, "SampleGrabber");
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

            if (videoControl == null)
            {
                //Connect still pin to samplegrabber
                hr = filtergraph.Connect(stillPin, samplePin);
                DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

                //Connect capture pin to render
                hr = filtergraph.Connect(capturePin, renderPin);
                DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
            }
            else
            {
                //Connect capture pin to render
                hr = filtergraph.Connect(capturePin, renderPin);
                DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

                //Connect still pin to samplegrabber
                hr = filtergraph.Connect(stillPin, samplePin);
                DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
            }

            //Get video properties
            saveVideoInfo(sampleGrabber);
            ConfigureVideoLocation(displayBox);

            //Run Graph
            IMediaControl mediaControl = filtergraph as IMediaControl;
            hr = mediaControl.Run();
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);


        }
        finally
        {
            if (sampleGrabber != null)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sampleGrabber);
                sampleGrabber = null;
            }
            if (capturePin != null)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(capturePin);
                capturePin = null;
            }
            if (renderPin != null)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(renderPin);
                renderPin = null;
            }
            if (samplePin != null)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(samplePin);
                samplePin = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Furthermore I configure my samplegrabber like this:

```
    public void configureSampleGrabber(ISampleGrabber sampleGrabber)
    {
        int hr;
        AMMediaType mediaType = new AMMediaType();

        //Set the values for media type and format
        mediaType.majorType = MediaType.Video;
        mediaType.subType = MediaSubType.RGB24;
        mediaType.formatType = FormatType.VideoInfo;
        hr = sampleGrabber.SetMediaType(mediaType);
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

        DsUtils.FreeAMMediaType(mediaType);
        mediaType = null;

        //Configure
        hr = sampleGrabber.SetCallback(this, 0);
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

    }
```

Comment: You keep saving to the same file, which potentially leads to concurrency writes.

Comment: Would this still not at least leave a name of the file? Currently it does not save anything. Also apart from that, is this the correct way of converting the image?

Answer (score 1):

Sample Grabber will not give correct MediaType for each sample grabbed, so don't bother requesting it from the sample here. Instead get grabber's input pin or camera's output pin and call IPin.ConnectionMediaType() to learn the correct media type of this stream.

Comment: How would I go about doing this? I set my capture and input pin in another function? I'll update the question with this method.

Comment: You need to query pin connection media type, rather than media sample media type. Media sample media type has a different meaning ([documented on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407009%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

I think your graph is not set up properly, and the samples are never passed through the sample grabber. On a first glance I think the sample grabber is never rendered. Connect the sample grabber output pin to a null renderer and things should work.

Comment: Where would I add the null renderer? In the `SampleCB` or within the graph making process?

Comment: In the graph making process. Add the null renderer to the graph and connect the out pin of the sample grabber to the null renderer.

Comment: Could you explain to me what this does exactly (Just trying to learn more about this library).

Comment: Sample grabber shouldn't be the last filter in a chain, it needs some other filter connected to grabber's output pin to pass samples to. One of the options is to use Null Renderer as such receiving filter. See this post for details: [Working with Sample Grabber in C#](http://www.infognition.com/blog/2013/working_with_raw_video_in_c_sharp_directshow.html)

Comment: I don't actually use a `ICaptureGraphBuilder`, Only a filtergraph. Is this a problem?

Comment: Or would I need to add a `ICaptureGraphBuilder` or would simply putting `filtergraph.render(outputPin);` work?

Comment: Just user the graph builder instance that you already have... all you need to do is add the null renderer and the connect sample grabber and null render... you are already doing this for capture pin and renderer pin in your code.

Comment: How would I go about adding a null render, I have never used one before and cannot seem to find one on the internet. Also when adding the sample grabber is it not already added when I use `hr = filtergraph.AddFilter(baseFilter, "SampleGrabber");` as I configure it here: `IBaseFilter baseFilter = sampleGrabber as IBaseFilter;
            configureSampleGrabber(sampleGrabber);` I will add my configureSampleGrabber method to the orignal post.

Comment: Or is this not the case?

Comment: Finally got it to work!, rewrote literally everything after crying. Thanks to Dee Mon's post :)